# Silverlight 3.0 navigation with transitions?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

Back in the day, during Silverlight 2 Beta 1 I've stumbled upon a piece of code at [flawlesscode.com](http://www.flawlesscode.com/post/2008/03/Silverlight-2-Navigating-Between-Xaml-Pages.aspx). The forementioned code enabled the user to navigate between xaml pages while employing some nifty hard-coded transitions like fading etc. Needless to say this still works in Silverlight 2.0 and to the best of my knowledge in Silverlight 3.0

I've recently watched a video by Tim Heuer, where Tim explains how does the new SL 3.0 navigation framework work. I haven't seen any examples of usage involving transitions - therefore I'd like to ask if anyone had any success attempting to use any sort of transitions with SL3 navigation framework ?

Best regads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

http://www.davidpoll.com/2009/07/19/silverlight-3-navigation-adding-transitions-to-the-frame-control/